# how to sync my iphone application calendar to iphone in built calendar using iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, calendar, icalendar, nscalendar, eventkit

Currently I am working on Calendar Application for iPhone. In this project i have to sync my application calendar to iphone in built calendar.

I created a calendar view which is similar to iPhone in built calendar but we can also place images with the date for recognize the event for this date.

I want to add an event on my application's calendar and it is also show on iphone in built calendar.

Please guide me, for the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides this capability through Event Kit.

Refer to the [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).